# how to emit (fire) axes_leave_event

Tags: python, pyqt, matplotlib

This is my first question of stackoverflow!  I've got a PyQT gui that's displaying an mpl figure canvas.  I've set the margins around my main axes to 0 so the plot will completely fill the figure canvas and the widget that contains it.  The problem is that when I do this I no longer get the `axes_leave_event` when I leave the figure canvas.  For example when I've clicked on the pan button in the `mpl_toolbar` my cursor changes to the cross-arrows but when I leave the widget I'd like it to return to normal and return to the cross-arrows when I reenter the widget.  If I don't minimize my margins around the axes then it works like I would like.  I can also connect the `axes_leave_event` but I don't want to connect it I want to emit it and can't figure out how to do that.

Thanks so much all.

My application is fairly large so I'll just show the code that I think is most relevent.

```
    def create_main_frame(self):
        self.dpi = 100
        self.fig = Figure((5.0, 4.0), dpi=self.dpi)
        self.fig.subplots_adjust(left = 0, right=1, top=1, bottom=0)
        self.map_canvas = MyDiagram(self.fig)
        
        self.add_axis()
           
        self.mpl_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.map_canvas, None)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.map_canvas)  


class MyDiagram(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, fig):
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.mpl_connect('axes_leave_event', self.testing)
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        if not event.size().height() == 0:
            FigureCanvas.resizeEvent(self, event)

    def testing(self, event):
        pass

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        FigureCanvas.leaveEvent(self, event)
        #If I could somehow get the 'axes_leave_event' to fire right here I would be set.
```

Comment: If you're not going to connect to `axes_leave_event`, what would be the point of emitting it?

Comment: When the event fires it changes your cursor to or from the chart cursor to the application cursor. I want this to happen but with my chart maximized the event does not occur. Basically I'm leaving the canvas without ever leaving the axes. I want to trick the axes leave event into occuring when I leave the figure.

Comment: But `axes_leave_event` is a notification: it _passes_ an event that has already occurred, rather than creating it. In order to emit it, you would need to create the relevant mpl event (which is different to the Qt event passed to `leaveEvent`). It would probably be easier to just update the cursor yourself using `MyDiagram.enterEvent` and `MyDiagram.leaveEvent`.

Comment: Your suggestion was my initial thought as well, but I couldn't quite figure it out. In the leaveEvent I added QtGui.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor() This works great, but what would I add in the enterEvent to bring back the appropriate cursor depending on what's checked on the toolbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat based on guesswork, since I can't test it with `matplotlib`, but something along these lines might work:

```
class MyDiagram(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, fig):
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self._cursor = None

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        if (self._cursor is not None and
            QApplication.overrideCursor() is None):
            QApplication.setOverrideCursor(self._cursor)
        FigureCanvas.enterEvent(self, event)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self._cursor = QCursor(QApplication.overrideCursor())
        QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
        FigureCanvas.leaveEvent(self, event)
```